# How can i delete a rectangle in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, draw, game-development

I tried to set the color of the rectangle the same as the background color, but i wonder if there's a more simple method to do it. This is what i've done:

```
screen = display.set_mode(500, 500)

BLACK = (255, 255, 255)
color2 = (127, 127, 127) #Grey

screen.fill(BLACK)
start_button = draw.rect(screen, color2, (190, 180, 120, 60))
display.update()
for i in event.get():
    if i.type() == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and mouse.get_pos[0] >= 190 and mouse.get_pos[0] <= 310 and mouse.get_pos[1] >= 180 and mouse.get_pos[1] <= 240:
        color2 = (255, 255, 255)
        display.update()
```

Anyway this is my first try with pygame, if you have any suggestions just tell me.

Comment: A lot of pygame programs re-draw the entire screen every turn of the main loop.  With this method you don't need to erase anything, you just stop drawing it.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can just fill the screen again and update the display if you want that.

```
screen = display.set_mode(500, 500)

BLACK = (255, 255, 255)
color2 = (127, 127, 127) #Grey

screen.fill(BLACK)
start_button = draw.rect(screen, color2, (190, 180, 120, 60))
display.update()
for i in event.get():
    if i.type() == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and mouse.get_pos[0] >= 190 and mouse.get_pos[0] <= 310 and mouse.get_pos[1] >= 180 and mouse.get_pos[1] <= 240:
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        display.update()
```

I also recomend you make buttons and checking if they are pressed using this
http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?lang=en&chapter=array_backed_grids